# Why can't I access the Internet after I changed the MAC address back and forth?

Tags: internet-connection, mac-address

I changed the MAC address on my computer to see how it works, using Technitium MAC changer. I browsed the Internet with this new MAC address. I then changed it back to the original.

Now I cannot access the Internet without a VPN. The Wi-Fi is connected and it says Internet access is available, but the browsers and other apps say no Internet connection. If I use a VPN, I get access to the Internet.

How do I revert what I've done?

Answer (score 2):

Do a complete shutdown. Turn off the modem and your computer. Wait a minute before you turn on the modem. Then turn on your computer.The modem then should detect the new address, assign the IP to it and it should work.

Comment: An internet "modem" (not usually a traditional analog<->digital modem any more, but that's irrelevant at the moment) can be a single-device connection "just a modem" or a "modem/router" that connects one or more wired devices plus (as indicated by "wifi is connected") one or more WiFi devices. Basically: 1 box or 2. So if it is just 1 box then the answer is correct. If there are 2 boxes (modem or gateway, router) then BOTH should be power-cycled. Should be obvious to the user, but then again that should have been the first step and not needed to be asked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to the ARP cache on your switch or router.  The ARP cache is used to keep track of which IP addresses map to which MAC addresses.  If you update your MAC address without notifying your network equipment, they will try to send traffic to the previous MAC address for some amount of time until the ARP cache entries expire.

The solution is to send an unsolicited ARP request (also known as a gratuitous ARP) to update the ARP tables on every device connected to your local subnet.  On Linux I would do this with the arping utility:

```
arping -U -I eth0 192.168.1.101
```

I looked up the program Technitium and it appears to be a Windows program, so the arping utility may not be available to you.  I would recommend searching through the documentation for Technitium to see if it offers a way to send an unsolicited ARP request.  I would think a program for changing MAC addresses should have this functionality, but as an alternative I found this thread on serverfault.com about arping on Windows which may be useful to you: https://serverfault.com/questions/69890/is-there-any-way-to-arp-ping-on-windows.